# can't access my tomcat service for high port like 8443,8080 as non-root user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tomcat, systemd, service

im running on my ubuntu server tomcat. I can start the service as `root` and can access my `localhost:8443`server.If i started the service as non-root like `tomcat`,the service will be started as tomcat ,but can't access my localhost:8443 webserver or rather don't answering me.

what i have done :

I. I add the user tomcat at first:

```
adduser tomcat ;addgroup tomcat
```

II. then i changed the service settings in `/etc/systemd/tomcat.service` from root to:

```
[Service] 
user=tomcat 
group=tomcat
```

III. changed the permission of my tomcat folder `/tomcat`:

```
chown tomcat:tomcat /tomcat -R
chmod 755 /tomcat
```

`netstate -nlp` ports 8080, 8443 -> good

`iptables -L -v` no dropped file -> good

`service started` as tomcat      -> good

But i can't still reach the server. If i changed the `user`,`group` to root in tomcat.service i reach the server.

I don't know where is the problem.

I'm grateful, if some experts can help me out.

kind regards

beardblack

Comment: Look in the logs: `$CATALINA_BASE/logs`. The most probable cause is Tomcat being unable to read the certificate and key. Also posting the entire `tomcat.service` might help. Are you aware, that most distributions have a ready `.service` file for Tomcat: e.g. [Debian 10](https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/tomcat9/blob/b0a9cb7bd46ac37deff7e0208afeb69f427dfa8f/debian/tomcat9.service)?

Comment: But why certificate? I can 't still access the server over the Port  8080 too

Comment: A wild guess, since you don't mention trying over `HTTP` in the question and you don't provide any other data. You have clearly a permission problem.

Comment: yes i thing, i know what the problem is. in sever.xml the key is in another folder for admin and the logs too. Maybe folder permission cause the problem. i will check it up and report you. but thx.